# Power BI: Change filter context for the map visual

Tags: powerbi

I need your suggestions regarding the map visual. I have a table with a list of events. Each event has a corresponding **latitude**, **longitude**, **start date**, and **end date**. **The date table** has an active relationship with the **start date** column.

My customer's requirement is to be able to use a date slicer to select any date period, and have the map to show all the active events **as per that date**. When the selected date period intersects with the period between the event **start date** and **end date**, such an event should be shown on the map.

Although I can change filter context and calculate all the necessary metrics related to active events as of any arbitrary date period, I am not able to make the map show me all the active events. It only shows the events with their **start date** falling within the selected date period.

I tried to put the active event indicator to the map filter area (**Active Events** is greater than 0), but it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new table "Active Dates", and add a measure that filters your events as

```
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Event') //Or whatever
  FILTER('Event',
    NOT(ISEMPTY(
      FILTER('Active Dates',
            'Event'[StartDate]<='Active Dates'[Date] 
         && 'Event'[EndDate]>='Active Dates'[Date]
)))))
```

You could also include extra logic to allow (Blank) [StartDate] and/or [EndDate], and something to exclude dates that are in the future (if these are appropriate).

If this is not efficient enough, you can change it to use `MIN('Active Dates'[Date])` and `MAX('Active Dates'[Date])`, rather than filtering 'Active Dates', at the cost of making your report only work if a contiguous range of dates is selected.